# Get lowest value in array and include duplicates

Tags: php, arrays

Say you have this array:

```
$users = [
    'a' => 2,
    'b' => 1,
    'c' => 1,
    'd' => 3
];
```

I need to get the keys with the lowest values. So in this case that would be `b` and `c`.

Currently doing it like this:

```
asort($users);

$lowestValue = array_values($users)[0];

foreach ($users as $k => $v)
    if ($v == $lowestValue)
        $lowestUsers[$k] = $v;

print_r($lowestUsers);
```

This works fine but is there  a more shorter/efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`array_keys`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to find the keys which have the lowest values in the array. If you pass `array_keys` a value as the second parameter it will return an array of all the keys which have that value in the array. Note that just using [`min`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) is probably the simplest way to get the lowest value:

```
$lowestValue = min($users);
print_r(array_keys($users, $lowestValue));
```

Output:

```
Array (
  [0] => b
  [1] => c 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/9RElL)

If you actually want the elements of the `$users` array which have the lowest value, you can take the output of `array_keys` and run it through `array_intersect_key`:

```
$lowestValue = min($users);
$lowestValueKeys = array_keys($users, $lowestValue);
$lowestUsers = array_intersect_key($users, array_flip($lowestValueKeys));
print_r($lowestUsers);
```

Although if that is the case it's simpler just to use `array_filter`:

```
$lowestValue = min($users);
$lowestUsers = array_filter($users, function ($v) use ($lowestValue) { return $v === $lowestValue; });
print_r($lowestUsers);
```

Output in both cases is

```
Array (
  [b] => 1
  [c] => 1 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/aZ3rr)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by the combination of [array_keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [min](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.min.php). There is no need of sorting or doing loops,

```
print_r(array_keys($users, min($users)));
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => b
    [1] => c
)
```

Working [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bcca82be7072214c79751a79fa5d0b2ee2bcbd29).

Answer (score 1):

This one helps you.

```
$users = [
    'a' => 2,
    'b' => 1,
    'c' => 1,
    'd' => 3
];

echo array_search(min($users ), $users );
```

Comment: array_search **only** returns the first matching key. OP wants to find **all** keys with the lowest value

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`min()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) function to find the lowest value in an array and [`array_filter()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function to filtering data. For example:

```
$users = [
    'a' => 2,
    'b' => 1,
    'c' => 1,
    'd' => 3
];

$lowest = min($users);

$result = array_filter($users, function($value, $key) use ($lowest) {
    return $value === $lowest;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

result:

> Array (
>       [b] => 1
>       [c] => 1 )

Answer (score 0):

Your have more options:

1. Use **min()** to get the minimum value and `array_keys($users, $minvalue)` to get related key (include duplicates)
2. Sort the array by using `asort($users)` and get minimum value with `$users[0]` (not showing duplicates)